# SSRS Migration Sharepoint Integrated to Standalone

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I'm using RS.exe to migrate from a sharepoint-integrated SSRS server to a standalone SSRS server. When I run the command I think SHOULD work, I get an error related to a missing SiteURL parameter. I want to copy all contents from the source SSRS box to the destination, so my understanding is that the defaults should be acceptable. Documentation for this migration path seems thin. I'd appreciate help in figuring out how to get this done.

Below are the command and error text:

> c:\IT>rs.exe -i ssrs_migration.rss -e Mgmt2010 -s http://SPssrs/ReportServer -v ts="http://reporting/ReportServer"
>
> Retrieve and report the list of items that will be migrated. You can cancel the script after step 1 if you do not want to start the actual migration.
>
> Retrieving schedules:
>
> Unhandled exception:
>
> The value for parameter 'SiteUrl' is not specified. It is either missing from the function call, or it is set to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
rs.exe -i ssrs_migration.rss -e Mgmt2010 -s http://SPssrs/_vti_bin/ReportServer -v ts http://reporting/reportserver
```

Comment: Thanks Riccardo, That got me on the right path. I had the SSRS server name and needed to use the sharepoint namespace instead.